# Transform XML to another format and add row number

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML and add row number
Example XML File like below :

```
<Wholesale>
<Customer>
<Name>abc</Name>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<Name>def</Name>
</Customer>
<Customer>
                <Name>hij</Name>
</Customer>
<Product>
        <productid>800</productid>
</Product>
<Product>
         <productid>900</productid>
</Product>
</Wholesale>
```

Would like this in the following format:

```
<Wholesale>
<Customer>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Product>
            <rowno>1</rowno>
            <productid>800</productid>
            </Product>
    <Product>
            <rowno>2</rowno>
            <productid>900</productid>
        </Product>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Name>def</Name>
    <Product>
            <rowno>1</rowno>
            <productid>800</productid>
    </Product>
    <Product>
            <rowno>2</rowno>
            <productid>900</productid>
    </Product>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Name>hij</Name>
    <Product>
            <rowno>1</rowno>
             <productid>800</productid>
    </Product>
    <Product>
            <rowno>2</rowno>
            <productid>900</productid>
    </Product>
</Customer>
</Wholesale>
```

Here is the XSLT but I cannot seem to add the rowno inside *Product*. Please comment on the XSLT transform that will insert it in there.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- At the ExternalBidAwardCustomer element, copy everything and sub include ExternalBidAwardCustomer-->
<xsl:template match="Customer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="../Product" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='WholeSale'>
<WholeSale>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Customer" />
</WholeSale>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Product)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Can any put me in right way, how to write a XSL for this ?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried (please add your code to your question)?

Comment: If you need a starting point...what I would do is start with the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) and add 3 additional templates to override the identity transform. In the first template I'd match `/Wholesale` and output that element (xsl:copy) and apply-templates to `Customer`. The second template would match `Customer` and would be the identity template (the xsl:copy/xsl:apply-templates portion) but also apply-templates to `../Product`. The third template would match `Product` and also be the identity template but add the `rowno` element using `xsl:number`.

Comment: I am able to transform however can you point out how to add rownumber inside <Product> ?

Comment: If you add your code to the question I can add an answer showing how to add the row number.

Comment: Added the XSLT code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Wholesale">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- collect all products ... -->
        <xsl:variable name="products">
            <xsl:for-each select="Product">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <rowno>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </rowno>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- ... and place them in each customer -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$products"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close with your XSLT. The main thing you need to change is the xsl:copy-of needs to be an xsl:apply-templates so `Product` will be processed and then add a template to process `Product` to add the `rowno` element.

Here's the updated XSLT. I've added "DAN" comments to note what I changed.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!--DAN: Added xsl:output and xsl:strip-space for formatting only.-->
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- At the ExternalBidAwardCustomer element, copy everything and sub include ExternalBidAwardCustomer-->
  <xsl:template match="Customer">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--DAN: Added node() to get Name and removed copy-of and added ../Product to 
        apply-templates with union operator.-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|../Product"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="WholeSale">
    <WholeSale>
      <!--DAN: Combined apply-templates.-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Customer" />
    </WholeSale>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--DAN: Added template to match Product so we could add rowno.-->
  <xsl:template match="Product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <rowno>
        <xsl:number/>
      </rowno>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Identity -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Product)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvgM

Comment: @nextbond - Good to hear it! Please consider accepting this answer (or the other excellent answer; whichever helped you the most) by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!